# Remove border of TD cell in collapsed table in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I'm working on creating a printable report(HTML table) that works on internet explorer.

The page should be (1)printable and should (2)work on internet explorer.

The page contains a table that should be (3)collapsed.

I'm trying to create a table similar to the following image

[image]

But what I'm getting is a table like the following image

[image]

The difference between two images is the unwanted horizontal borders in the second image.

This is the code I'm working on

```css
/**************************************
Section 1
***************************************/
.buyback-table {
    border-spacing: 8px 6.5px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 39px;
}
.buyback-table th, .buyback-table td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 7px 7px 7px 9px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: solid 2px #000000;
}
.buyback-table.buyback-collapse {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.borderless-space {
    border: none !important;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center !important;
}
/**************************************
Section 2
***************************************/
/*.hide-vertical {
    position: relative;
}
.hide-vertical:after, .hide-vertical:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: white;
}
.hide-vertical:before {
    bottom: -2px;
}
.hide-vertical:after {
    top: -2px;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="buyback-collapse-container">
    <table class="buyback-table buyback-collapse">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Cost/Mile</th>
                <td style="width: 5%" class="borderless-space"></td>
                <th>Miles</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>$0.00</td>
                <td class="borderless-space text-center" style="width: 5%">X</td>
                <td>0 miles</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>$34,704.00</td>
                <td class="borderless-space text-center" style="width: 5%">X</td>
                <td>3,574 miles</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>$0.00</td>
                <td class="borderless-space text-center hide-vertical" style="width: 5%">X</td>
                <td>0 miles</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="borderless-space" colspan="3">
                    Other Data:
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">Owner Contribution</td>
                <td class="borderless-space hide-vertical"></td>
                <td>$4,297.83</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In the above code, CSS has two sections. Section 1 has the basic css for the table which results in the first image, and section 2 contains the css for fixing the issue to generate the second image.

If you uncomment code in section 2, a possible solution is applied to the code.

The problem with my solution in the snippet above is that using `before` and `after` is not good for printable reports; When I export the report to a PDF file, the position of `before` and `after` blocks changes, and instead of hiding the unwanted horizontal borders, it moves view pixels in different directions.

I don't want a solution by implementing a table with collapsed borders, because the table cells should be close to each other. I've already tried that and it makes table cells disjoint.

I'm working on Internet Explorer, and advanced css grid layout didn't work with me.

Is there another way I can implement to hide the unwanted horizontal borders shown in the second image above?

Comment: just remove  `colspan="3"`

Comment: @AntonyJack What if the `Other Data:` text is very long? In that case the row will only take the size of one column instead of three, so that doesn't really fix the issue.

Comment: I can see that your code works for the IE 11 browser and it is causing the issue in the Chromium browsers. I suggest trying to make a test with the `border-top-color: transparent; border-bottom-color: transparent;` to see whether it makes difference. If you want proper styling when printing then try to use `@media print {CSS code}`.